# Xcode 4.6, connecting two text fields

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I am a beginner in Xcode and I need to get two text fields to work so when you enter a number into one text field and one into another, you get another number. I am almost done however, I am stuck at this part:

```
- (IBAction)checkAnswer 
{
    [_textAnswer resignFirstResponder];
    if ([_textAnswer.text isEqualToString:@"42"])
        here--> [_textAnswer2 resignFirstResponder];

     if ([_textAnswer2.text isEqualToString:@"52"])
    {
        _labelResult.text = @"48";
    } 
    else 
    {
        _labelResult.text = @"Unavalable!";
    }
```

Here is the link to what I am trying to do...

http://i42.tinypic.com/33ubdxi.png[/IMG]

I need to find a way to connect these two sections of code for the text field together but I can't find the code I need anywhere.

Comment: I didn't really got what you're asking. Can you clarify what is the goal you want to achieve please?

Comment: Little bit of an edit required to your question. Post the code instead of an image...

Comment: What does it do wrong? And are you missing any brackets or you really cancel the second text field as responder based on the value in the first field?

Comment: Your link to tinypic isn't a link. Can't you simply describe in your own words, what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to guess that the problem is that only 1 of the fields is really considered and that this is what you want:

```
- (IBAction)checkAnswer 
{

[_textAnswer resignFirstResponder];
[_textAnswer2 resignFirstResponder];

if ([_textAnswer.text isEqualToString:@"42"] && [_textAnswer2.text isEqualToString:@"52"])
{
    _labelResult.text = @"48";
} 
else 
{
    _labelResult.text = @"Unavalable!";
}
}
```